# How to make a JFrame one colour?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to add some polish to a small game I made and, every time a round finishes, I'd like the whole JFrame to flash white and quickly lose opacity until you can see the game again. How would I do this?

Note: I'm thinking about hiding all the components and adding a JPanel on top that loses opacity quickly but this doesn't seem right (and I'd like to be able to see the components behind the white flash as it goes from opaque to transparent).

Comment: add a new `jpanel` on top of the components and change its colour from opaque white to transparent

Comment: Color the JFrame's glasspane and make it visible. Using a Swing timer change its opacity.

Comment: how would i add it on top of all the components?

Comment: there are many layout mangers that allow you to do it like *MigLayout*.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do i set it's colour? I've tried setting foreground and background, then making it visible, but haven't found a setColour() method.

Comment: You're thinking British. In the colonies it's "color". Regardless, it's `setBackground(Color c)`, and it should work. If it doesn't, then post your attempt. @Blip: no need to add a JPanel or use a layout manager since the glasspane is already there, and already sits on top of the JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes you are correct.

Comment: calling setBackground(Color c) on the getGlassPane() method did nothing, but I set the glasspane to a JPanel whose background color I set and that worked. Still want me to post the code that didn't work for me? (and if yes, as an edit or as a new post?)

Comment: No, if your code is working, then go for it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the JLayer class. Take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html).

The tutorial has examples that:

1. paint translucent layers
2. do animation

Put the examples together and you should have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fading out image to achieve the same. AlphaComposite is used for fading effect.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
```

Refer [Fade Out Image](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Fadeoutanimageimagegraduallygetmoretransparentuntilitiscompletelyinvisible.htm) to access the sample code.